# GIT LFS "failed to push some refs to" <local repository>

Tags: git, tfs, git-lfs, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have a current GIT repository hosted via TFS. We are planning on migrating to LFS to manage some large binaries that are stored via source control. I am cloning the TFS repository to my local PC, and then cloning the clone so that I can simulate/test making these changes rather that push my LFS changes up to TFS while team members are working.

TFS->Local Clone->Local Working Clone

I do the following steps/GIT commands:

1. Clone from TFS. creates a bare local repo:

   ```
   git clone --mirror TFS-URL LocalClone
   ```
2. Clone to a working repo:

   ```
   git clone d:/LocalClone CloneWorking
   ```
3. switch to my CloneWorking repo:

   ```
   cd d:/CloneWorking
   ```
4. Install LFS:

   ```
   git lfs install
   ```
5. run BFG and remove an old binary:

   ```
   java -jar D:\bfg\bfg.jar --convert-to-git-lfs <some Zip File> D:\CloneWorking\.git
   ```
6. Cleanup GIT garbage:

   ```
   git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
   ```
7. Create a test file and ensure pushes to Origin are still successful:

   ```
   get add .
   git commit -m "sanity check"
   git push origin master --force
   --Success--
   ```
8. Begin tracking binaries extensions via LFS:

   ```
   git lfs track "*.zip"
   ```
9. At this point, there are several .zip files that appear to be modified:

   ```
   git status
   new file:   .gitattributes
   modified:   <Some Path>/A.zip
   modified:   <Some Path>/B.zip
   ```
10. I do an add/commit and try to push to origin:

    ```
    get add .
    git commit -m "This is going to fail"
    git push origin master --force
    Uploading LFS objects: 100% (9/9), 42 MB | 0 B/s, done. EOF error:
    failed to push some refs to 'd:/LocalClone'
    ```

So this is where I am stuck. If i cannot push to an upstream repo on my local machine, I'm pretty sure this is going to fail when I attempt to push these changes to a remote repo on the TFS server.

Answer (score -1):

[Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) is an extension to Git which commits data describing the large files in a commit to your repo, and **stores the binary file contents into separate remote storage.** When you clone and switch branches in your repo, Git LFS downloads the correct version from that remote storage.

Afraid you are supposed to push it to remote repo url not your local repo.

```
https://tfsseverurl.com/Collection/Project/_git/Reponame
```

Besides,  you need to use TFS version at least 2017.2 or above according to this link-- [LFS support in TFS on premise](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/538)